# Can't redirect to the same url using htaccess when www is used

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to keep my laravel website without www in the beginning of the url.

I am using two .htaccess files. One at root directory and one at public_html folder. Here is my directory tree structure:

```
-mysite
    -app
    -bootstrap
    -config
    ...
    -public_html
        .htaccess
        index.php
        -css
        -js
        -images
        ...
    -resources
    -routes
    ...
.htaccess
```

This is what I want to do.

Input:

`www.mysite.com`

`mysite.com`

Output that I need:

`mysite.com`

**Now, the problem:**

`www.mysite.com` gives me: `mysite.com/public_html/index.php`

(The www is being removed successfully)

**These are my htaccess files:**

Root directory:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

# Allow Installatron requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} deleteme\.\w+\.php
RewriteRule (.*) - [L] 

RewriteRule ^ public_html/index.php [L]
```

public_html directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Remove www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm using hostinger by the way.

Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: This is confusing: "I am using two .htaccess files to achieve that, one at directory root and one at public_html folder." Actually in a normal setup those folders are one and the same.

Comment: This somehow looks as if you are using different `DOCUMENT_ROOT` settings for the two hosts. _Why?_

Comment: @arkascha sorry, my explanation was really bad. I edited my question, please take another look.